# Force live users to expire assets for JS Web Apps

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

Our web application is built on AngularJS and Ruby on Rails. Sometimes we find a bug in the JS and need to patch it immediately. We push up an update to Heroku and the new JS files are then live. However, users on the site (who are currently on the site) and do not refresh their page, are still using the old JS file.

Is there a way to force refresh of the assets on deployment with Heroku? Or, is there a better way to handle this type of problem?

I am thinking of using web sockets to possibly handle the scenario.